# Troubles with a proof from Kunen's book

Tags: set-theory

I'm studying Godel's constructible universe and those statements that are true inside it: specifically $L\vDash\lozenge$. In this regard, I need to understand the following Lemma from Kunnen's book Set Theory (2011).

> $\bf Lemma\ III.7.12\ $ *Let $\theta$ be an uncountable cardinal, and let $M$ be countable with $M\preccurlyeq H(\theta)$. Then*
>
> 1. *If $a\in M$ and $a$ is countable, then $a\subseteq M$*.
> 2. *$M\cap\omega_1$ is a countable limit ordinal*.
> 3. *If $\theta=\omega_1$, then $M$ is transitive*.
> 4. *If $\theta\gt\omega_1$: $\omega_1\in M$ and $\omega_1\not\subseteq M$; if $\beta=M\cap\omega_1$ and $\operatorname{mos}$ is the Mostowski isomorphism from $M$ onto a transitive $T$, then $\operatorname{mos}(\omega_1)=\beta$ and $\operatorname{mos}(\xi)=\xi$ for all $\xi\lt\beta$. Also $T\vDash ZFC-P$ (if $\theta$ is regular), and $\beta=(\omega_1)^T$*.

I'm having troubles with the proof of the first statement. More concretely I don't understand who the condition $M\preccurlyeq H(\theta)$ allows the author to state the following:

> $\bf Proof.$ For $(1)$, note that $\omega$ and all smaller ordinals are definable in $H(\theta)$, so $\omega\in M$ and $\omega\subseteq M$. Assume that $a\neq\emptyset$ (otherwise the result is trivial); so there is a function $f:\omega\overset{\text{onto}}\longrightarrow a$. *All* such $f$ are in $H(\theta)$, so $M\preccurlyeq  H(\theta)$ implies that *some* such $f$ is in $M$. Now every element of $a$ is of the form $f(n)$ for some $n$, and $f$, $n\in M\to f(n)\in M$ (by $M\preccurlyeq H(\theta)$), so $a\subseteq M$.

So for example:

- It is clear that $\omega$ and the natural numbers are defined in $H(\theta)$, but why are they defined in $M$?
- Why is there a function $f$ that lies in $M$ as a consequence of $M\preccurlyeq H(\theta)$?
- Why $f(n)\in M$ as a consequence of $M\preccurlyeq H(\theta)$?

Every help or comment would be much apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you perhaps be persuaded to reveal the _title_ (and, for extra credit, publication year) of the "Kunen's new book" you're referring to?

Comment: Oh, for sure: I'd forgot it. Its title is Set Theory. I've already edited my post.

Comment: It appears that Kunen has written two books with that title. One published by Elsevier in 1980 (with the subtitle "An Introduction to Independence Proofs"), and one published by College Publications in 2011. So the title needs to be qualified by the publication year.

Comment: It's Kunen's Set Theory from 2011: for this reason in my previous post I said "Kunen's new book" hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that each of the natural numbers (and indeed, the set of all of them) are definable without parameters. So $M$ can run this definition as well, and get 'its version' of $\omega$. But then elementarity tells you that this version must be the real $\omega$, and M's natural numbers the real natural numbers.

If $a \in M$ and is countable, then the statement "$a$ is countable" is true. But this is a statement that only involves the parameter $a$, which is in $M$. So $M$ can make it as well, and again, elementarity tells us that it must be correct about this. But this means $M$ thinks that there is some function $f$ from $\omega$ onto $a$ which is in $M$. But then again, by elementarity, $M$ must be correct about these properties of this function.

Finally, $M$ thinks that $f$ is a function whose domain is $\omega$, and $n \in M$ as we have seen above. So then $M$ sees that $f(n)$ is defined, and again, $M$ must be correct about the statement "$f(n)$ is defined". So then if $M$ thinks that $f(n) = b$, by a final application of correctness, $M$ must be correct about this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @tci for your help!

Comment: Regarding 4: Why $\beta=(\omega_1)^T$? Is because $(\omega_1)^M=\omega_1$ and the Mostowski function is an isomorphism? If it would be the case, how can we proof that $(\omega_1)^M=\omega_1$?

Comment: It's not. The thing is that $\omega_1 \cap M = \beta = \mathrm{sup}(\omega_1 \cap M)$. To see why, use the fact that if $\alpha \in M$ is a countable ordinal, then $\alpha \subseteq M$ (here use this stuff about countable sets that he mentions). For a transitive $T$ though, notice that from the fact that $M \cap [\beta, \omega_1) = \emptyset$ but $\omega_1 \in M$, the image of $\omega_1$ under the Mostowski collapse must actually be $\beta$ (can't be less because those ordinals are already in $M$, can't be more because $M$ has no ordinals in the gap).

Comment: OK, now it's clear that the Mostowski collapse of $\omega_1$ is $\beta$, but why the $\omega_1$ of $T$ (that is $(\omega_1)^T$) is the Mostowski collapse of $\omega_1$? Is it because $\beta=\omega_1^M$, $\pi(\beta)=\beta$ and $\omega_1^T=\pi(\beta)$? (Here $\pi$ denotes the Mostowski function)

Comment: Well, we need to be a bit careful. It is not the case the $\beta = (\omega_1)^M$. We know that $\omega_1 \in M$ and $\beta \not \in M$, so $(\omega_1)^M = \omega_1$. But $(\omega_1)^M$ satisfies a certain parameter-free formula which $\pi((\omega_1)^M)$ must also satisfy (since the Mostowski collapse must respect this formula), namely, saying that "it is $\omega_1$".

Comment: So, how can we prove $(\omega_1)^M=\omega_1$?

Comment: Because $\omega_1$ is definable without parameters, so the same definition can be applied in $M$, and $M$ must be correct about this.

Comment: Oh right... Thank you very much for the umpteenth time! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, $\omega$ is definable - by a formula $\varphi$ - in $H(\theta)$. So $H(\theta)\models \exists! x\varphi(x)$. (Here "$\exists!$" is shorthand for "there exists a unique".) By elementarity, this means $M\models\exists! x\varphi(x)$. Let $m\in M$ be such that $M\models\varphi(m)$. Then by elementarity, $H(\theta)\models\varphi(m)$. So $m=\omega$.

Similarly, every finite ordinal is definable in $M$ in the same way it is definable in $H(\theta)$ - and hence in $M$.

Moving on: suppose $a\in M$ is countable. Then by elementarity, $M$ thinks that $a$ is countable. This means that $M$ thinks there is a bijection $f$ from $a$ to $\omega$. By elementarity, $H(\theta)$ also thinks $f$ is a bijection from $a$ to $\omega$ - that is, $f$ *really is* a bijection from $a$ to $\omega$.

Now suppose $b\in a$. Then - in $H(\theta)$ - we have some $n\in\omega$ such that $f(b)=n$. So by elementarity, $M\models\exists x(f(x)=n)$. (Note that this uses that $n\in M$.) Let $c\in M$ be such that $M\models f(c)=n$. Then by elementarity, $H(\theta)\models f(c)=n$, that is, $f(c)$ really equals $n$. But then $c=b$, so $b\in M$.

Comment: Thank you very much @NoahSchweber for your help!

Comment: Regarding 4): Why $\beta=(\omega_1)^T$? Is because $(\omega_1)^M=\omega_1$ and the Mostowski function is an isomorphism? If it was the case, how can we proof $(\omega_1)^M=\omega_1$?